# Mahalaya Period

Tags: belief, tradition, science

Normally Mahalaya comes in the month of Purattasi. But this time it comes in Avani month itself and the first day of Purataasi is Mahalaya Amavasya. Some opinion is that this is not a good sign for the world; it indicates the adharma has increased multiple folds. Can this be answered with suitable posts?

Comment: every 2 1/2 yrs the cycle gets repeated souramana and chandramana panchanga difference just like krishna jayanthi

Comment: @Prasanna  I am seeing the mahalaya in avani for the first time at the age of 54. Your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Mahlaya paksha always celebrated in bhathra pada masa krishna paksha as per chandramana it never differs but avani puratasi is sun based calendar mismatch will occur every 2 1/2 yrs as difference is adjusted by addhika masa it should be repetable

Comment: Seems irrelevant

Comment: As far as I know (for Telugu people ),  the Mahalaya Paksha starts on krishna paadyami of Bhadrapada maasa and ends with amaavaasya in the same month.   Do Tamil people follow different method? Can you explain?

Comment: Mahalaya is common for all brahmins. Do not separate and answer.

Comment: You stated in the question content  - **Normally Mahalaya comes in the month of Purattasi. But this time it comes in Avani month itself and the first day of Purataasi is Mahalaya Amavasya.**  I could not understand  the meaning of Purattasi and Avani.   Can you explain?

Comment: Avani and Purattasi are Tamil months. Relevant is Simha and Libra month.

Comment: So Āvaṇi represents Shrāvaṇa and Puraṭṭāsi represents Bhādrapada, in Tamil tradition of Solar calendar system.  Thanks for the information.

Comment: You had stated - **Normally Mahalaya comes in the month of Purattasi. But this time it comes in Avani month itself**.  Only Tamil astrologers can explain, in my view

Comment: Telugu precedes 15 days from Tamil calendar. For you also this year mahalaya  is in advance. Check with the well known persons.

Comment: As far as I know, Telugu people follow a mixer of Solar and Lunar system.  Normally, we follow the system of Mahalaya Paksha, starting from  krishna paadyami of Bhadrapada maasa and ends with amaavaasya in the same month.   So for us Bhadrapada maasa is important, whether it coincides with Solar system or not.  No Telugu astrologer predicted any bad omens due to what you are saying according to Tamil System.  So I cannot answer your question.

Comment: You have clarified your stance. Bharatha Desa consisting of cultures differing from state to state.But the solar/lunar systems are same. Amavasya and pournima will not change region to region or state to state.

Comment: Please watch the video.  It is about adhika maasa.  It may be useful to you.(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5SEQuEi288) @ParthasarathyRaghavan

Comment: Sure. Will watch and let you know. Thanks for the inputs.